# How to compare elements of a row string in one dataframe column with elements of a row string of another dataframe column, and remove non-matching?

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes with different row counts.

df1 has the problems and count

```
problems          | count
broken, torn      | 10
torn              | 15
worn-out, broken  | 25
```

df2 has the order_id and problems

```
order_id    | problems
123         | broken
594         | torn
811         | worn-out, broken
```

I need to remove all rows from df1 that do not match the individual problems in the list in df2. And I want to maintain the count of df1.

The final df1 data frame would look like this:

```
problems          | count
broken            | 10
torn              | 15
worn-out, broken  | 25
```

I have only done this for columns in the same dataframe before. Not sure how to deal with multiple data frames.
Can someone please help?

Comment: so in this example, nothing should be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to merge the two df's together:

```
(pd.merge(df.assign(problems = df['problems'].str.split(', ').map(frozenset)),
          df2.assign(problems = df2['problems'].map(frozenset)),on = 'problems'))
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: I made an edit to include the `on` parameter, as your real `df` might have other columns

Comment: hmm thanks but I still get the error. I have converted the problems list in df2 into just strings now. That might help. Now instead of comparing a list and the string, you just need to compare individual elements of one row of df1 to individual elements of df2 (problems column). If you know the solution, you can let me know.

Comment: I have edited the question for better understanding.